# Issues with the compatibility of getRepository() function in MongoDB DocumentManager and Persistence ManagerRegistry

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine

I am getting this error:
Compile Error: Declaration of Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager::getRepository($className) must be compatible with Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry::getRepository(string $persistentObject, ?string $persistentManagerName = null)
Has anyone ever seen this error?
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmFeU.png)

I tried to manually modify the class to make it match but it didn't work because it kept giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:
Mistaken implementation in the DocumentManager